# CSS Filter grayscale: I want it Black

Tags: css

I am using the following css to convert my color images to grayscale.

```
img.desaturate{
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: url(desaturate.svg#greyscale);
    filter: gray;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
}
```

BUT I want it **Black** (rgb(0,0,0) or #000000), and not grey. Is it possible?

Comment: FYI your last `filter: gray;` rule will negate the previous two filter rules.

Comment: How **Black** is this **Black** exactly?

Comment: Black, like in #000, rgb(0, 0, 0)...what do you define as black?

Answer (score 70):

Try using:

```
filter: brightness(0%);
```

Comment: Awesome! So simple.

Answer (score 12):

I supose you want only black & white images, like a vector image or something, that's it?
You could try playing with the saturate brightness and contrast filters:

```
filter: gray saturate(0%) brightness(70%) contrast(1000%);
```

[Demo in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aJDBy/)
(Demo only works in Webkit, I'm too lazy to write all vendor extensions :P)

Comment: Why the fiddle doesn't work? It works for me, however, only works in webkit browsers (Chrome18+, Webkit nightly, Safari 6+...). Filters are not supported in other browsers as you can see [here](http://caniuse.com/css-filters). If you want a cross-browser pure-css solution I think it isn't possible...

Comment: yeah I have the latest version of chrome: 24.0.1312.57 m....It is just strange that the filters do not give you an otion to set the amount of grey - or to make it pure black...

Comment: So strange. I have Chrome 26 and works perfectly...  [Screenshot](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/90/69051953.jpg/)

Comment: This worked for me on webkit(chrome): `-webkit-filter: saturate(0%) brightness(0%) contrast(100%);`

Comment: I wanted a black background in the check box when checked. This worked perfectly for me . Thank you :)

Answer (score 6):

I'm late to the party, but here's the best solution I found so far:

```
filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

I see that this is old question, but couldn't you apply a background-color to the parent element that is black and use `opacity` to fade the child `img`?

Answer (score 1):

The filter values that you need depend on the content of your website (images, background colors, etc'). For my site `filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(70%) contrast(2);` works.
Just play with the values until you get something you like.

Answer (score 1):

The pro who wrote this:

https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp

Says to turn it black do this:

```
brightness(0) saturate(100%)
```

Answer (score -1):

I would try using the saturate filter rather than grayscale to get the black color. Here's a link on david Walshe's site you can play with the settings...

http://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-filters.php