# CSS grayscale filter changing logos to different shades

Tags: html, css

I am using the grayscale filter on a slider with logos in it. I'd like all of the logos to be filtered to the same shade of gray. As you can see below, depending on the color of the logo, each is getting filtered to a different shade.

Here is my CSS:

```
section.fullwidth .carousel-exhibitors .logo-wrapper .tint img {
       position:     relative; z-index: -2; 
       filter: gray; 
       -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); 
       -webkit-transition: all .6s ease; 
       -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

[image]

Is it possible to filter them all the same shade?

Comment: I don't think you can do this with a filter as a filter always respects differences in the original (i.e. the colours of the original logos).  I think this looks pretty good, but the simplest way to achieve what you want is to modify the logos to all be the same shade of grey in the first place and do away with the filter (though I accept that might not be what you want or are able to do within your situation)

Comment: yeah, I am trying to avoid that, as I use the same image in multiple places on my website and only want to have the grayscale here in the slider. If it can't be done, I'll have to deal...

Comment: Just thought - is there a way to make the image pure b/w then apply grey filter...Will dig a little

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15904211/css-filter-grayscale-i-want-it-black

Comment: it's best to do this before you upload the images anyway. It saves load time and performs better

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I managed it (with the help of the previous post I pointed to) without SVG...

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fd1dgd7c/3/)

Code:

```
<img src="https://www.google.es/images/srpr/logo4w.png" class="image">
```

Css:

```
.image {
    -webkit-filter:  grayscale(100%) brightness(60%) contrast(10000000%);
    opacity: .3;
}
```

**Unfortunately**, if you have to support IE then you are still going to get colour - it doesn't have an equivalent to contrast - I don't believe it, but I should have!

Back to my very original point - if you have to support all (lowly) browsers, create copy images in b/w and fade to gray and save the images like that in the first place.

Comment: if you use  `filter:  saturate(0%);`, this works without opacity http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPqxJR (second image)

Comment: Best approach, but reverse the fiddle to opacity-having wrapper, because that was the working way.

Comment: Btw, you don't need the wrapper at all, just set the opacity on the `img` itself.

Comment: Thanks for the optimisations. It was getting late!

Comment: I do not get  what is the purpose of opacity unless to see background-color or background-image of the page ?

Comment: You need the opacity to get gray.  Without it the filters return pure black and white images.

Answer (score 2):

As PaulG said, this is impossible, because all filters are relative to original colours. However, there is one moment: if your logos are transparent (which means they use transparency instead of white colour as background), you could run an SVG filter such as this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<defs>
  <filter id="binarize">
    <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic"
      type="matrix"
      values="0 0 0 0 .4
              0 0 0 0 .4
              0 0 0 0 .4
              0 0 0 1 0" />
  </filter>
</defs>
</svg>
```

This matrix dismisses RGB colours from the target pixel and uses it's opacity multiplied by 0.4 as new RGB. 40% is the shade, can be changed. Such filter can be applied via adding it to html and this css:

```
filter: url(#binarize);
```

Or you could save it to file binarize.svg and:

```
filter: url(binarize.svg#binarize);
```

However, this is mostly theoretical, not all browsers support SVN filters and surely not all logos have right transparency. Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vq3uLbcw/) for example. If you don't use Mozilla, **prefixize** the filter property.

Comment: This approach requires too much restrictions on the logo images. They cannot use partial opacity, for instance. Also, I used another image in your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gstzk7fe/).

Answer (score 0):

you could look, as well,  at those 3/4 different ways to turn black and white your logos:

> filter:grayscale();
>
> mix-blend-mode
>
> filter:url(); + svg (here saturate type) equals in css `filter: saturate(0%);`

**[demo to play with](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPqxJR)**

```css
div {
  background: #fff;/* #000 - #fff works for blend-mode to turn gray , any other color will be used blue>blue&white */ 
}

img {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
          filter: grayscale(100%);
  width: 30%;/* demo*/
}

img:first-of-type {
  mix-blend-mode: luminosity;
  -webkit-filter: none;
          filter: none;
}

img:last-of-type {
  filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'saturate\' values=\'0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
}
```

```html
<div><img src="http://www.creads.fr/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/logos.jpg" /><img src="http://www.creads.fr/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/logos.jpg" /><img src="http://www.creads.fr/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/logos.jpg" /></div>
```

Comment: None of the picture looks like "the same shade" to me.

Comment: @SergeSeredenko that is maybe the idea, at lieast in FF the SVG is the less 'dark', in chrome, they all look the same. What browser did you use ? (if IE, forget it, it only works with SVG ... )

Answer (score 0):

I just faced this same issue and fixed it by manually setting the `opacity` (between 0.3 and 0.7) value for each image, ended up working out quite well.